# Is the map from a pointers to his integer representation gomomorphic?

Tags: c++, pointers

Let `f: Pointers -> Integer_Represenataion` be a map provided by implementation (I hope, that map doesn't depends on the way we cast a `pointer` to an `integral type`). Let be a pointer to `T` and be a variable of integral type.

Does the standard explcitly define that the map is isomorphic, i.e. `f(p+i)= f(p)+i*sizeof(T)`? In general I would like to understand how additive operation between pointers and integrals is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't. The specification does not require anything for it. It is implementation-defined and some implementations may be weird.

In similar cases it always helps to remember the memory models on 8086 (in 16 bits). There pointers are 32-bits, segment+offset, but they overlap to form only 20 bit address. In huge mode, these are normalized to smallest offset.

So say `p = 0123:0004` (which converts to `f(p) = 0x01230004`), `i = 42` and `sizeof(T) = 2`. Then `p + i = 0128:0008` and converts to `f(p+i) = 0x01280008`, but `f(p) + i*sizeof(T)` = 0x01230058`, a different representation, though of the same address.

On the other hand in large model, the pointers are not normalized. So you can have both `0128:0008` and `0123:0058` and they are different pointers, but point to the same address.

Both follow the letter of the standard. Because arithmetic is only required to work on pointers to the same array or allocated block and the conversion to integer is implementation defined completely.